# DHCP Issue on home network

Tags: networking, dhcp

I have an issue on my home office network - I'm not a networking expert in any way but I have a home network with a Samba NAS and an internal webserver for testing websites (my main role).
The PlusNet router is putting out DHCP in the range 192.168.1.100-199.   Servers are fixed IP.
Client machines are picking up DHCP in the range 192.168.10.100- 200 with a default gateway of 192.168.10.1  - no devices on the network have this IP address and I cannot work out where this device is.

```
Wireless LAN adapter WiFi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : 802.11n USB Wireless LAN Card
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-36-76-01-70-01
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::495c:e9ba:9e2d:607c%13(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.126(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 14 December 2021 10:21:17
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 15 December 2021 10:21:16
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 738211446
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-21-AC-DD-3C-A4-BA-DB-FE-C9-98
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.1
                                       8.8.8.8
                                       114.114.114.114
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Looking a the arp -a results I get:

```
Interface: 192.168.10.126 --- 0xd  (Wifi on my PC)
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.1.7           d4-5d-64-ef-85-85     dynamic  (My PC)
  192.168.10.104        00-0b-82-41-14-e3     dynamic  (Grandstand IP Phone)
  192.168.10.113        00-f3-61-8e-f8-21     dynamic  (The Alexa)
  192.168.10.129        86-5f-83-17-ff-25     dynamic
  192.168.10.255        ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  226.178.217.5         01-00-5e-32-d9-05     static
  239.255.255.253       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fd     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
```

I have started experimenting with SMART home - with Alexa and some bulbs but I cannot get Alexa to connect either - I don't think this is the problem though as when I unplug the Alexa the problem remains.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Dave

Comment: Isn't 192.168.10.1 assigned to the router ...?

Comment: No.  The router is 192.168.1.254.  Which is also the one meant to be sending out DHCP which is what's confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks kedanek for the response.  After much trial and error it seems that a WavLink external AP is to blame.   Despite no documentation to tell you it's going to do this.

(Admin if you want to delete this that's fine)

Comment: Kudos to your hard work :)